# How to get name of a field with relationship on Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

How do I see the name of a related field instead of ID?

I have a `Product` table and `Category_Product` table. In table `Product`, I have a fields `cateproduct_id` (number type) I want to get it into my front end. But it shows a number.

Have any method to convert `cateproduct_id` to a name of category product?

Example: get name of category is `Nokia` instead of `cateproduct_id = 4`.

Here is the controller Product like:

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::with('cateproductId')->get();
    return view('duan/list', compact('products'));
}
```

The model of Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function cateproductId(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category_Product::class);
    }
}
```

In the admin, I get list category and choose a category for my product.

In the frontend page, I need `get name category of Product` instead of `get id category of Product`:

```
<div class="list">
    @foreach($products as $item) 
        <h1>{{$item->cateproductId->name}}</h1>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I tried to debug like:

```
<div class="list">
    @foreach($products as $item) 
        {{dd($item)}}
    @endforeach
</div>
```

result like:

```
#relations: array:1 [▼
    "cateproductId" => null
  ]
```

Comment: did you try to specify the foreign key in the relationship: return $this->belongsTo(Category_Product::class, cateproduct_id);
because by default it will look for a matching categoryProduct_id in the products table.

Comment: thanks @user3681740. It's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the foreign key in second parameter

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function cateproductId(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category_Product::class,'cateproduct_id');
    }
}
```